# Splashscreen activity is not killed when clicking on backbutton

Tags: android, splash-screen

Here is my code. Pretty simple..But when I click on the back button,the second activity appears..

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    this.finish();
  }

}
```

I have also put in the manifest file but again I still have the same problem..

```
        android:noHistory="true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Handler` like this for making `Splash` screen

```
private static final int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                openLandingActivity();
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);//
    }

    protected void openLandingActivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Why the complext `onKeyDown()` instead of `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: both doing the same thing its basically the choice of coder

Comment: Yes using the postDelayed method is another way which works as well. Actually I going to use post() later on for my app:). Thank you again my friend.

Answer (score 3):

```
} finally {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setClass(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
   finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you switch to an AsyncTask that sleeps for 3 seconds during doInBackground() and starts the new activity + kills the current one in onPostExecute(), but only if isCancelled() is not true.

Then override the onBackPressed() of your splash activity and:

1. Cancel the current async task (hold a reference to it in a local variable).
2. Finish the current activity.

This way the AsyncTask will still sleep in the background for 3 seconds, but when its onPostExecute() comes it will know that it was cancelled by checking isCancelled() and not start the second activity.

See: [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Hope it will help you..

```
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 5000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
             Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            splash.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the onKeyDown() method which makes the problem to disappear..Here is the fixed code..

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  private boolean isBackPressed = false;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                if(!isBackPressed){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
 }


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        isBackPressed = true;
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}

}
```